# How do I install scientificpython package successfully on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have installed Python 3.7.6 on my Ubuntu 18.04 system. I am trying to install package called "scientificpython" but consistently getting the following error message.

```
(base) jit@jit-VirtualBox:~$ pip install scientificpython
Collecting scientificpython
  Using cached ScientificPython-2.9.4.tar.gz (688 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/jit/anaconda3/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o8a8hyd1/scientificpython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-o8a8hyd1/scientificpython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-o8a8hyd1/scientificpython/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-o8a8hyd1/scientificpython/
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-o8a8hyd1/scientificpython/setup.py", line 72
        print "netCDF not found, the netCDF module will not be built!"
                                                                     ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("netCDF not found, the netCDF module will not be built!")?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

How do I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your traceback and the [ScientificPython home page](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/ScientificPython/):

> Therefore ScientificPython can be used only with Python 2.7 and NumPy 1.8, but not with later releases of either software.

You are using Python 3.7.6, which does not recognize `print` as a statement as it existed in Python 2, for starters.

You can [install Python 2 from source](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-2717/), or use a tool such as [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to manage multiple Python versions alongside each other.

Answer (score -1):

Try to install ScientificPython by specifying the version

> Command:

```
pip install ScientificPython==2.9.4
```

> Or Try:

```
python -m pip install ScientificPython==2.9.4
```

If problem still persist,  then try to download the tar file of the package then install it manually. Available links are provided.

```
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a2/8e/6306c88c0e937af38ed3a40e2a08caf30c53ad7f33e2928f14ae2cf53961/ScientificPython-2.9.4.tar.gz
```

Or

```
https://src.fedoraproject.org/lookaside/extras/ScientificPython/ScientificPython-2.8.1.tar.gz/
```

Or

```
https://osdn.net/frs/g_redir.php?m=kent&f=anuga%2Fanuga_support_software%2Fubuntu_8.10%2FScientificPython-2.9.0.tar.gz
```

But ScientificPython works only with Python version 2. So it is recommended to use the alternative package called Scipy.

> Command:

```
pip install scipy
```

Or

```
python -m pip install --user numpy scipy matplotlib ipython jupyter pandas sympy nose
```

I hope it would resolve the error.

Comment: ScientificPython is compatible with Python 2 only. Specifying the version will make no difference if trying to install with Python 3.